# Jersey 2.18 + GAE raises NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey

[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) version 2.18 (released on 05-Jun-2015) onwards + Google App Engine raises `NoClassDefFoundError` with an error message *"javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details."*

Below is a part of the stack trace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.Concurrent$GetManagedExecutorService.compute(Concurrent.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.cache.Memoizer$1.call(Memoizer.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.cache.Memoizer.compute(Memoizer.java:51)
        ... 78 more
```

Jersey version 2.17 (released on 11-Mar-2015) does not raise this error at least in my development environment.

How can I use the latest version (2.22.1, released on 07-Oct-2015) of Jersey with GAE without encountering this error?

<sup>I know *"The JRE Class White List"*.</sup>
<sup>https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jersey version 2.22.1 without problems. Here are my maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
</properties>
```

It is possible that you accidentally included one of the other jersey components, like `jersey-container-jetty-servlet` which are not compatible with app engine.

Comment: My dependencies are `jersey-container-servlet-core`, `jersey-media-moxy` and `jersey-mvc-jsp`. The point is that no error is raised when `${jersey.version}` is `2.17`.

Comment: Oh, the combination of jersey-media-moxy 2.17 + other jersey dependencies 2.22.1 does not raise the error.

Comment: Looks like you found your culprit. I use jackson as you can see, maybe that's an alternative?

Comment: +1 You showed me that the version 2.22.1 of `jersey-container-servlet-core` and `jersey-mvc-jsp` works on GAE and it helped me narrow down the scope of the problem. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. A possible solution could be that you download the moxy source code and overwrite the code yourself, mkyong has done something similar here http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/gae-jsf-javax-naming-initialcontext-is-a-restricted-class/ - The only other options i see are using a different json provider or to open a ticket for moxy and hope they find a different solution.